# Azure ARM template 1 ip, 1 port, 1 loadbalancer, 3 vms

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

Hello guys (and gals),

I'm in progress of rewriting my loadbalancer setup in Azure, because I obviously did it wrong the first time.

What I want is simple, 1 ip -> 1 loadbalancer -> port 8080 external, port 8080 internal -> 3 virtual machines (which all hosts the same application on port 8080).

So if 1 virtual machine goes down, then there are 2 other to pick up the pace.

I have looked at templates like this one: https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-2-vms-loadbalancer-natrules which looks very nice, except this `"frontendPort": "[copyIndex(5000)]",` which means that the frontendPort will be `5000`, `5001` and `5002` for 3 virtual machines.

So now I ask, does anyone have any idea how I manage to load balance between multiple virtual machines in Azure, using an ARM template, without using multiple public ports?

Update: I have tried creating multiple NICs (1 for each VM) all pointing to the same NATRules in the loadbalancer, and I'm told multiple NICs are not allowed to use the same rules :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just take [this example](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/201-2-vms-loadbalancer-lbrules/azuredeploy.json) and modify `loadBalancingRules` to use 8080 instead of 80. this way you will use a single port for all vms. you also need to modify probe port.

NAT Rules (which you are looking at) are something different. you cant load balance nat rules, hence different ports used for different vms.